# How to use Model.query() with promises in SailsJS/Waterline

Tags: javascript, sails.js

I'm having issues with Sails.JS. I would like to use promises with the Model.query() function (I use sails-mysql adapter).
I use promise as follows:

`var Promise = require('bluebird');
 var patientQueryAsync = Promise.promisify(Patient.query);`

but it does not work. It returns `ReferenceError: Patient is not defined`, has anyone meet the same problem? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Waterline supports promises out [of the box](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline#promises) so there is no need to promisify.

```
Patient.findOne()
.where({ id: 5 })
.then(function(patient){
  //do something
  return patient.lastVisit;
}).catch(function(err){
   // An error occurred
})
```

query however is not warped in a promis so it needs to be promisified (this worked for me):

```
var query = Promise.promisify(Patient.query);
query('SELECT name FROM patient').then(function(results) {
  //do something
});
```

Answer (score 0):

think that [this](http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/queries) works for you. " Waterline queries implement a partial integration with the Bluebird promise library"

```
Patient.find()
.then(function (allTheStuff) {...})
.catch(function (err) {...});
```

[Promises](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline)

> Promises use the Bluebird library, so anything you do after the first
>   then call (or spread, or catch), will be a complete Bluebird promise
>   object. Remember, you must end the query somehow (by calling then or
>   one of the other functions) in order to complete the database request.

```
User.findOne()
.where({ id: 2 })
.then(function(user){
    var comments = Comment.find({userId: user.id}).then(function(comments){
        return comments;
    });
    return [user.id, user.friendsList, comments];
}).spread(function(userId, friendsList, comments){
    // Promises are awesome!
}).catch(function(err){
    // An error occurred
})
```

Answer (score 0):

`.query()` does not support promise in sails.js. I deal with the problem with the method from https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/3418
It works well.

Answer (score 0):

> Since the **models** in sails.js is global. You can see this settings under
>   *config/global.js*.
>  Make sure you already define you patient model under
>   api/models. Even it is inside the folder you still can call the model too.
>   Do not forget to specify at least one key inside your model object
>   like i did in the following.
>
> /**  * Model for order.  *  * @description :: This model will works
>   toward all function inside the order feature.  */
>
> module.exports = {   tableName: 'order_seller' };
>   
>   After that your above code should work. Test it with Postman for covenience.

```
 var Promise = require('bluebird');<br>
 var query  = "SELECT *FROM SOMETHING";
 var runQuery = Promise.promisify(Patient.query);
 runQuery(query).then(function(){}).catch(function(){});
```